# Struggling to update webpack-dev-server using NPM?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Recently there has been an update with the Angular CLI that is supposed to have fixed a high vulnerability in regards to `webpack-dev-server`.

This is the error that continues to show up:

[image: Error Message]

So I then ran this command:

[image: Command Run]

In  theory this should fix it right? The error should only occur with a version less than 3.1.11. But then if I check under installed packages it hasn't really updated it at all. There are now two different versions installed?

[image: List Returned]

Therefore the error is still there. I tried to delete the `node_modules` folder and run an `npm install` but it does not change anything.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a problem in the dependency of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, you need to upgrade `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to the version that has the upgraded `webpack-dev-server`.

What you did, basically installed latest `webpack-dev-server` as your dependency.

**UPDATE**

Looks like the change to `webpack-dev-server@3.1.14` has landed in `master` and not yet released. [Comment on merged PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/13277#issuecomment-450704370)

Comment: I now ran `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest` , it still produces the same error.

Comment: Updated as per my findings.

Comment: Okay great thank you! Will update this when it has been released.